# How populate grid on EJS(Embedded JavaScript templates) with Express and Nodejs connected to MySql

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have Express with Nodejs connected to a MySql db
and I can populate a list on my ejs page but I am searching for an example where I can load a grid like slickgrid,datatable etc either passing rows or json

Thanks for any assistance

my route

```
var data;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  connection.connect();
  connection.query('SELECT * from crg_version', function(err, rows) {
    data = JSON.stringify(rows);

    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
    console.log(rows);

    res.render('drugdb', { title: 'Express', name: 'Sippy', items: rows});
  });

  connection.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

my view with list

```
  <% include templates/header.ejs %>

  <ul>
    <% if(items.length){

      for(var i = 0;i < items.length;i++) { %>
        <li><%=items[i].desc%></li>

     <% }

   } %>
  </ul>

  <table id="example"></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you're looking for, although it would probably be better to set it up in the front end and manage it with javascript.

```
<table>
<% if(items.length){

    for(var i = 0;i < items.length;i++) { %>
      <tr>
        <% for (var j in items[i]) { %>
        <td><%=items[i][j]%></td>
        <% } %>
      </tr>
   <% }

} %>
</table>
```